# Merge arrays together based on different values

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I am having trouble thinking of the logic with the following problem:

I have the following array (has been snipped, as its much larger)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [code] => LAD001
            [whqc] => GEN
            [stocktag] => NONE
            [qty] => 54
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [code] => LAD001
            [whqc] => GEN
            [stocktag] => NONE
            [qty] => 6
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [code] => LAD004
            [whqc] => HOLD
            [stocktag] => NONE
            [qty] => 6
        )

)
```

I basically need to comebine all the keys in this array so that where the code, whqc and stocktag are the same, add the qty values together. With the example below, I need to end up with this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [code] => LAD001
            [whqc] => GEN
            [stocktag] => NONE
            [qty] => 60
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [code] => LAD004
            [whqc] => HOLD
            [stocktag] => NONE
            [qty] => 6
        )

)
```

As the first and second keys of the array had the same code, whqc and stocktag, the qty's have been added together into the one key.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why isn't this in a database?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: The OP might not have access to an SQL database, or the usage may be one time and not warrant such overhead.  Perfectly reasonable thing to do in code.  Though obviously if the data was from a database, a `GROUP BY` clause with a `SUM()` would be much preferable.

Comment: This isnt in a database because it is loaded from a spreadsheet first, then the data is massaged before it is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest combining the group values in to a hash, storing the full array under the hash as a key and if you have a duplicate, add the quantity, then do `array_values()` to pull the results.

```
$aggregated = array();
foreach ($records as $cRec) {
    // The separator | has been used, if that appears in the tags, change it
    $cKey = md5($cRec['code'] . '|' . $cRec['whqc'] . '|' . $cRec['stocktag']);

    if (array_key_exists($cKey, $aggregated)) {
        $aggregated[$cKey]['qty'] += $cRec['qty'];
    } else {
        $aggregated[$cKey] = $cRec;
    }
}

// Reset the keys to numerics
$aggregated = array_values($aggregated);
```

Comment: That did EXACTLY what I was after. THank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like:

```
   $output = array();
    foreach($array as $details){
        //make distinct key
        $key = $details['code'].'_'.$details['whqc'];
        if(!isset($output[$key])){
            $output[$key] = $details;
        }else{
            $output[$key]['qty'] += $details['qty']; 
            $output[$key]['stocktag'] = $details['stocktag'];
        }
    }
    $output = array_values($output);
    print_r($output);
```

update: Orbling was first ;-)